# Combining word objects in VBA

Tags: vba, object, ms-word

I have created three Word objects in VBA, which are; A, B and C.

I want to combine these into one single Word object called, D.

I have attempted to acheive this via a document merge to no avail.

My source is as follows:

```
Set p_appWord = p_appWordContent.Merge(p_appWordGeneral)
```

`p_appWord` is the main object and (`p_appWordContent` + `p_appWordGeneral`) are sub-objects.

Comment: You'd better include your code if you want to have some answers, please edit your post to add it.

Comment: I added my source code to here.

Comment: Are you truly trying to "merge" the documents or do you wish to simply concatenate all documents into one, i.e. create one document from three? Because with "merge" you are merging revisions.

Comment: I wish to simply concatenate all documents into one. Because I need to create 1 document with 600 pages, performance is not good. So i want to create many object words then combine them.

Comment: Improved readability while preserving the original content.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example to achieve what you wish for three documents, merged into one new one:

```
Dim a As String, b As String, c As String, d As Document
Dim r As Range

a = "path to first doc"
b = "path to second doc"
c = "path to third doc"
Set d = Documents.Add

Set r = d.Content
r.InsertFile a, Link:=False
Set r = d.Range(d.Content.End - 1, d.Content.End - 1)
r.InsertFile b, Link:=False
Set r = d.Range(d.Content.End - 1, d.Content.End - 1)
r.InsertFile c, Link:=False
```

If you wish to do this for a variable number of files, you need to loop over them. Here is an example, please set a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime:

```
Dim d As Document
Dim r As Range
Dim fso As FileSystemObject, fol As Folder, f As File
Dim fc

Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set fol = fso.GetFolder("path to your files")

Set d = Documents.Add

For Each f In fol.Files
    Set r = d.Range(d.Content.End - 1, d.Content.End - 1)
    r.InsertFile f.Path, Link:=False
Next f
```

**Edit**
If you wish to merge all currently opened documents into one without iterating over files, use this:

```
Dim d As Document
Dim r As Range
Dim allDocs As Variant

ReDim allDocs(Documents.Count)

For i = 1 To Documents.Count
    allDocs(i - 1) = Documents(i).Name
Next i

Set d = Documents.Add

For i = 0 To UBound(allDocs) - 1
    Documents(allDocs(i)).Range.Copy
    Set r = d.Range(d.Content.End - 1, d.Content.End - 1)
    r.Paste
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but i do not want to create word document in a folder, i want to create object and then combine to 1 object. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Amended code to merge all currently active documents.